# Exiting Schengen from Cruise

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, cruising

We are cruising from Barcelona back to Fort Lauderdale, Florida in November. The cruise goes to a couple of spots in Spain and then has 7 days at sea and then a couple other days at other locations before reaching Florida. Where does the exit stamp from Spain/Schengen happen? This is a concern to us as we are in Europe often and have to count our days in the 90 day period to be compliant.

Comment: I assume the answer will depend on which 'other locations' you are visiting between Spain and the US.

Comment: Exactly, a full itinerary of the cruise is needed in order to answer the question...

Answer (score 4):

You're supposed to get the exit stamp before leaving a port in the Schengen area for a port outside the Schengen area.  For example, if you sail from Spain to Morocco to Portugal to the US, you'll get two Schengen departure stamps, one from Spain and one from Portugal (with an entry stamp from Portugal in between).  If you sail directly from Spain to the Azores, you won't get a departure stamp from Spain.  If the "other locations" are entirely non-Schengen ports then you should get an exit stamp on the day of your last departure from Spain.

Comment: Just curious: how is this enforced? If a ship sails from Spain to the Azores but then makes a stopover (intentional or not) in Morocco, will the border guards in the Azores know? Probably there is a tracking service for cruise and cargo ships (just like FlightRadar), but what if it's a private yacht?

Comment: Our ship goes to a couple places in Spain/Canary Islands then to the Bahamas. So... that means I need them to stamp it in the Canary Islands before we take off to the Bahamas?

Comment: Curious what happens if the last stop is skipped - eg the ship plans to call at the Canaries or Azores but has to miss it due to weather or some other reason.  Presumably there will be no exit stamp and  the only evidence will be the entry stamp of the next port of call.